# Algolia Firebase and Android integration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

In my Android app, I am using Firebase as a database. I want to add some search capability and after my research I have found that Algolia is proper for me.

Algolia's [Firebase tutorial](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/firebase-algolia#familiar-with-firebase) explains how to integrate my existing Firebase database with Algolia. In this tutorial, they provide some Node.js code (which I am not familiar with). In the first gathering of data, I just copied the integration code, did the necessary changes and ran it on Windows terminal: the data is now imported from Firebase to Algolia.
But there are some other necessary specifications like updating, removing data. They also provide some js codes for this purpose, but I really dont know how to attach this listeners in my android app with this js code.

Can anybody give me an idea how it is properly done?

Comment: Check out this article : http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/12/09/algolia-real-time-search-with-firebase/ It's based on the old Firebase but I think you'll get an idea.

Comment: It is the same tutorial with the link. I dont know where to put these codes in android?

Comment: Are you trying to index your data from an Android app, or do you want a concrete example of how you can do it from your computer? If you wanted to do the former, it is not a good idea: as any client implementation of Algolia, an Android application should not contain any secret. This means you should only use **search-only API keys** on such an application, and do your indexing with another API Client.

Comment: @starrystar i also want to integrete my firebase with algolia. but the above link is not working!! i don know what to do now.

Answer (score 2):

From the phrasing of your question, I'm not sure if you want to learn *how to search* your Firebase data in Algolia from an Android app or if you are *trying to index/update/delete* your Firebase data from an Android app.

---

### Searching your data from an Android app

If you want to search your data from an Android app, there are a few guides to get you started.

- You should check the [Android Instant Search Result Page Guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/instant-search/android#introduction), which guides you through the implementation of a complete search result page from the data model to building the UI:

[image: Android Instant Search Guide screenshot]

- You can also check the [Android API Client Search Documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/android/search#search-in-an-index), which contains concrete examples of how you can search your data as well as general advice on using Algolia efficiently:

### [image: Android API Documentation screenshot]

### If you wanted to index/update/delete your data in Android

If you were trying to write to your data from an Android App, this is not a good idea: an Android app is easy to decompile or intercept to read secrets like your **Algolia API Key**, which is why in an Android application or in any *front-end* implementation of Algolia you should only use your **Search-only API Key** to ensure nobody could mess with your data inside Algolia.

I advise you to read [Algolia's Security Best Practices](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/best-security-practices) to learn more on security with Algolia (specifically the entries **Secure your Admin API Key** and **API Key security**), and to have a look at [Algolia's Guide on API Key Security](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys#api-keys) for a guide on using **Algolia's Secured API Keys** feature.

Comment: Ok I am not sure I can explain myself. I have indexed my existing data with running node.js code on Windows terminal. I have arrange the searched part on android. I have a search view and I can search through the list. But I am confused when it is come to update delete data from firebase. Because, the tutorial gives the javascript code. In the first place I have run to index my data. But how can ı configure update delete data indexes. Where to put js codes on my android app.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated my answer acccordingly: you should only **search** in your data from a front-end (such as an Android App) and do any **indexing/updating/deleting** from a back-end (such as your computer running node.js scripts). For security reasons, you should **only do searches from an Android app**. Any other operation should be done from **a machine you control.**

Comment: Thank you for your update. I think you understand my question. As I understand, when I update my firebase data, I will run the script from my windows terminal. There is no need for automatically check. Am ı right? If the script run in backgorund and listen firebase continiosly I dont know how to run continuosly?

Comment: You are right about manually updating your data from a script on your Windows machine. In the [guide you mentioned](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/firebase-algolia#add-or-update-data), under **Add or Update Data** you can see that we use Firebase's `fb` object to react to events (`fb.on('eventname', ...)`). This means the script is meant to run continually, but will only do work when it will receive Firebase's event (in this case `child_added` or `child_changed`).