# How to use Algolia in Android with Firebase content

Tags: android, search, firebase, algolia

I made an app where anyone can sell a product: you set its details and then I save it in Firebase.

On the client side (Android app) I want to be able to search for products using plain text.
I think the best way is by using Algolia but I really have no idea how to set-it up. Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: This doesn't help? https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/

Comment: I really don't have any experience with Node.js so I don't know where to use those scripts

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/deltaepsilon/firebase-search

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are actually two topics in your question: **how can one link Algolia to a Firebase database** and **how can one build an Android app with Algolia**. I'll cover both in my answer.

## How to link Algolia to Firebase

You will need to use a scripting language to **import your existing data**  into Algolia and to **sync the changes when your data is updated**. Algolia has a [guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/) to help you do so using Node.js.

You don't need to be experienced with Node.js to do it! Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331107/algolia-firebase-and-android-integration) where an Android developer like you with no prior experience of Node.js just followed the guide:

> In the first gathering of data, I just copied the integration code, did the necessary changes and ran it on Windows terminal: the data is now imported from Firebase to Algolia.

**You simply need to:**

- Copy the code samples from [Algolia's Firebase guide](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/)
- Replace the credentials with [yours](https://www.algolia.com/api-keys)
- Run the scripts from your computer (if you never ran js scripts locally, search for a Node.js beginner's guide like [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/) or [this](http://blog.gvm-it.eu/post/20404719601/getting-started-with-nodejs-on-windows))

Once your data is imported in Algolia, you can move on to step 2:

## How to use Algolia in your Android app

For building your search interface with Algolia, the recommended tool is [InstantSearch Android](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android). It's a toolbox that provides you **plug-and-play components** to build your search interface quickly: InstantSearch will handle all the network-related issues, the data-binding, and many other things so you can focus on what's specific to your app.

You can have a look at [InstantSearch Android's demo apps](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android-examples) which will show you examples what you could build using this tool, like this Media demo:

[image: Media app example]

Algolia also provides an [Android API Client](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/android/) for building apps. It lets you interact at a lower level with Algolia: you send the requests, get the results as `JSONObject` and decide what you want to do with it.

Most projects should use **InstantSearch Android** as it is built to make your development easier and faster (and it actually uses the Android API Client under the hood!)

Comment: My team, and I are having issues with cloning InstantSearch Android repository. Can you have a look?

Comment: Hey @BugsBuggy, thank you for reporting this and sorry you are experiencing issues! I'm checking it now and will keep you updated.

Comment: @BugsBuggy I sent you an email to debug further! If you didn't get it, just send something at support@algolia.com and I'll follow-up :)

Comment: Another way I found to run this was delete any one module from the available two, i.e. either Media or E-commerce.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is pretty surprising, there may be a discrepancy between the two apps' build settings. I'll investigate !